# Using LINQ to XML to traverse an HTML table

Tags: c#, html, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

So, I can easily use LINQ to XML to traverse a properly set-up XML document. But I'm having some issues figuring out how to apply it to an HTML table. Here is the setup:

```
<table class='inner'
       width='100%'>
    <tr>
        <th>Area</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Zip Code</th>
        <th>Type</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Essentially, there can be an endless number of rows, I want to be able to go row-by-row to check the data accordingly. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Should I be using tools other than LINQ for this?

**EDIT**: Sorry about the confusion, my issue is the fact that the page I am trying to gather data from is HTML, not XML. The exact extension is ".aspx.htm". This doesnt seem to load properly, and even if it did I'm not certain how to traverse the HTML page, given that there is one table before the table I'm trying to get data from.

For example, here is the XPATH to the table I'm trying to get info from:

```
/html/body/form/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td/table
```

Comment: you probably need to rephrase your question. I'm not seeing what's the road block from the description you have above ... causing the answers to be variations of use .Elements() / loop, even when you mentioned you have used linq to xml before.

Comment: @eglasius Yeah, thanks for the tip. I really didnt explain what my main issue was. Edited.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
XElement myTable = xdoc.Descendants("table").FirstOrDefault(xelem => xelem.Attribute("class").Value == "inner");
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<XElement>> myRows = myTable.Elements().Select(xelem => xelem.Elements());

foreach(IEnumerable<XElement> tableRow in myRows)
{
    foreach(XElement rowCell in tableRow)
    {
        // tada..
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you have an XElement with the `<table>`, you can loop through its child `Elements()`.

Answer (score 0):

linq is like sql it performs set based operations.

You want to focus on using a foreach loop to iterate over the selected set of xelements -